# Angular drag and drop form builder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, editor

I am trying to create a certificate generation application using Angular

for that, I need to place input fields on the certificate. (something like drag and drop).

I am planning to build from scratch using div and using dynamic forms in type script, is there any plugin for creating a form with drag and drop/add field elements inside the form.

can anyone provide useful links,

Thank you.

Comment: I think this library can be useful here https://github.com/formql/formql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice, after some research I found a better plugin "formio" 
this helpful plugin that had a lot of options and easy to integration hope this will help you as well.

Refer : https://formio.github.io/ngFormBuilder

Comment: You should be using the updated version for Angular 8 at https://github.com/formio/angular-formio. Demo found at https://formio.github.io/angular-demo/#/forms/builder. Disclaimer: I created this library.

Comment: Hi ! in angular formio , I face some challenges like when i try to call an API to auto fill some data in the form , I am unable to get that .

Is there any other package or tool available that has advanced interactions with API  in form builder

Answer (score 11):

You should give https://github.com/formio/angular-formio a try. You can see a demo at https://formio.github.io/angular-demo/#/forms/builder

Disclaimer: I created this library.

Comment: Hey Travis, Thanks for developing the library. I have one question,  can we add custom HTML for drag-drop in formio.
for example.. I want a drag-drop star rating system.

any response will be helpful

Comment: @Travis Tidwell, thank you for the wonderful library. I was wondering if there are any options to configure tab options shown when setting up a form field. Example: I want to hide all tabs like `Validation|API|Conditional|Logic and Layout`.
The intent is to provide only Display and Data tabs to users.
Once again, thank you for the library and appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using

1. https://github.com/shakalya195/angular-5-formbuilder 
   This one has a built in custom validators (http://formbuilder.shakalya.com),
2. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-form which has features for features drop scopes, custom styling, disable drag/drop & drag handles
3. You can also try using the formbuilder npm package (A jQuery plugin ) https://www.npmjs.com/package/formBuilder
4. Angular Drag-Drop FormBuilder
   A PEN BY Lam Phuoc Thinh - you can find a form builder made using jquery